# question related to Iphone autorelease usage

Tags: iphone, memory-management, autorelease

Could someone help me please understand how allocation and memory management is done and handled in following scenario. i am giving a Psuedo code example and question thats troubling me is inline below:

```
interface first  
{ NSDecimalNumber *number1;  
}

implementation  
.....

-(void) dealloc {  
 [number1 release];  
 [super dealloc];  
}


=================================  
interface second  
{ NSDecimalNumber *number2;  
}  

implementation second  
.....  
- (First*) check  
{  
    First *firstObject = [[[First alloc] init] autorelease];  
    firstObject.number1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];   
                    **// do i need to autorelease number1 as well?**  
    return firstObject;  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for voting down this question, this is a basic memory management question for which the answer can be found in the Apple developer documentation.  
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html  

But to answer your question: you have to autorelease or release number1.

Comment: @Moszi If you download all questions that can be answered by the basic documentation you'll soon run out of your daily vote allowance. :-)

Comment: @middaparka hahh :) - i like the "first read, then ask" approach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct as is. If you autoreleased the object, its reference count would reach zero and it would be dealloced, and then if you later tried to use the value stored in number1 your app would crash.

The only enhancement I'd add is releasing any existing value. i.e.

```
[number1 release];
number1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];
```

If you don't do this, the previous object assigned to `number1` will leak each time `check` is called.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if number1 has been instantiated prior to the initial release?

Comment: @middaparka No. It'll be set to `nil` initially and calling a method on a `nil` value does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the enhancement suggestion. This helps

Comment: i just clarified on number1's allocation on which i had question. If i am doing alloc/init each time check is called and number1 is an instance variable for firstobject, Do you still suggest there be a need to release it first?

Answer (score -1):

As you're allocing the NSDecimalNumber, you need to release it. (As you're doing so in the dealloc.)

Whilst it's hard to provide a meaningful example based on your sample code (as "number1" isn't actually used), the general rule is that you're responsible for any object you `alloc`, `copy` or `new`. If the object was only required in the scope of a function, you could of course autorelease it.

There's a good blog article over at http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/ that I'd recommend reading as it provides good examples (including some edge cases) and is easy to follow.

Comment: You don't **need** too. It's up to the developer if he wants a bad, memory-leaking application. :) as you know, I've overwritten NSObject's alloc method in a category so it doesn't retain the object once but arc4random() number of times.

Comment: `number1` is an instance variable, so we can assume it's needed outside the scope of this method (in dealloc if nowhere else).

Comment: @grahamparks Yup - I was updating my answer to mention that he was doing the right thing releasing it in the dealloc.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped clarify some other doubts i had as well